# Java用の手軽なBenchmarkライブラリ

Tags: java

Java用の手軽なBenchmarkライブラリ/フレームワークがあったら教えてください。

[Golang の Benchmark](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) くらい手軽に使えることが望ましいです。

よって、最も Golang の Benchmark に近いモノを教えていただいた解答を accept したいと考えています。

---

追記、こういうのは **マイクロベンチマーク** って言うべきもののようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これとか如何でしょうか。
https://github.com/tokuhirom/nanobench

使い方をみるとだいぶお手軽に使えるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。使い勝手は最高です! ただ結果の表示において、1オペレーションあたり何ナノ秒かかったのかみたいなのが無く、そういう情報が結構重要だったりします。

Comment: ソースコード読んでみて、こちらをベースにオレオレライブラリを作るのが良さそうだと判断しました。ありがとうございました!

Answer (score 2):

jmh はどうでしょうか?

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

@Benchmark だけ使えばシンプルかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほどその手がありましたね。ただベンチマークを書き始める前&実行するところがシンプル(手軽)とは言いがたいという印象です。でもおかげでmicrobenchmakというタグを付けておいたほうが良いと気が付きました。